# Add Column from another datatable

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I am having two Datatables : dt1 and dt2. Now dt1 is having datacolumn something like:

**Monday | Wednesday | Thursday**

but doesnt have anything in datarow yet.

Now,in dt2,the data is something like:

**StartTime | EndTime**

```
   7:10 | 8:00

   8:00 | 9:00

   9:00 | 10:00
```

I want to merge both datatable so that i can get Datatable something like:

**StartTime | EndTime | Monday | Wednesday | Thursday**

```
   7:10 | 8:00

   8:00 | 9:00

   9:00 | 10:00
```

Please help me :(

This project is to design School timetable.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Also,,,suggest me that is it good to use datatable?or should go for table control for Timetable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can copy the columns without rows like this:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt1.Columns)
        {
            dt2.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType);
        }
```